# Use PS3 Controller via USB

Tags: ros, microcontroller, usb, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there were any libraries for ROS for using a PS3 controller through the USB connection instead of the Bluetooth connection? Or if it is even possible?

I looked at ps3joy, but it seems to only work via the bluetooth pairing.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43921/use-ps3-controller-via-usb/) by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-09-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the regular [joy driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy). It will probably work.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-17**:
Confirmed; the PS3 controller shows up as a standard joystick when attached via USB, so the joy driver works wonderfully.

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2014-04-16**:
On 12.04 LTS3, I had to do a few non-obvious steps to get the DualShock 3 controller to work in USB: A) run 'sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-joystick'; B) after connecting the gamepad via USB, before or after running joy_node, I had to hold the PS button for 2 seconds to activate it.